# Is memory, that is allocated in a thread, alife after the thread terminates?

Tags: c, multithreading, memory-management

I experience some memory allocation problems and try to detect possible reasons for these problems.

There are many possible reasons, and lots of hours must be spent to check each of them.

One of the possible reasons is that there is a memory buffer, that is allocated within a thread, and this buffer is used after the thread terminates.

So, if there is a chance that thread termination causes memory deallocation, then many hours of debugging may be avoided.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: If you are allocating buffers in your thread and, effectively, transferring ownership to another thread in some way that the reference to them are not lost, then you should be fine.  No system I know of keeps track of allocated memory on a per-thread basis, (and if one did, it would make threads almost useless).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it does, although it of course might depend on your particular details.

Generally, memory allocation from the operating system's point of view is a per-process activity, while threads exist *inside* the process. So if one thread allocates memory and then dies, the operating system doesn't clean that up since the process is still alive. Memory is shared inside the process, so the OS can't know that the memory no longer is used and can be cleaned up.

Answer (score 1):

No, threads that 'die' do not deallocate any memory.

When a thread ends, the thread itself vanishes from memory, like a function does once it's done executing. It will take all the 'stack' objects with it, but all the memory you allocated yourself (i.e. malloc) will still be there.

As such, before you end your thread, you should make sure that all dynamic memory that was used by the thread and is not needed any more is freed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Anything on the thread's *stack* (a local variable, for example) becomes invalid when the thread ends. However, if the data is in the *heap*, then the memory is still valid as long as the process is running. Of course, you'll need to save the pointer to that heap allocation somewhere outside that thread.

Answer (score 0):

Memory allocated by a thread behaves like memory allocated by a method call:

- variables on the stack will be dealocated when the method returns (thread terminates)
- variables on the heap will continue to be allocated unless explicitly deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all answers, I'd like to make a note that **pthread** has a TLS keys which are registered with **pthread_key_create** which accepts key ID and destructor functions. On **pthread_exit** a static **pthread_key_clean_all()** is called that iterates through the keys and invokes assigned destructors that may perform memory deallocation (by application design).
So, to understand that - search in your code all **pthread_key_create** invocations, check if a destructor assigned and the put breakpoints to all of them to check what and in which order is destroyed.